# Liquibase error when trying to update change set log to DATABASECHANGELOG

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to run below create statement in liquibase

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset userName:1
CREATE TABLE JOB_INSTANCE
(
    INSTANCE_ID BIGINT       NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    VERSION         BIGINT,
    JOB_NAME        VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    JOB_KEY         VARCHAR(32)  NOT NULL,
    constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

- My liquibase version is 4.3.5
- Mysql version is 8.0.32
- JDBC connector version is mysql-connector-java-8.0.26

Below are my liquibase properties.

```
changeLogFile=changelog/db-changelog-master.xml
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://server-host:3306/schema?serverTimezone=UTC
username=root
password=*******
liquibase.hub.mode=off
```

JOB_INSTANCE get created successfully.

I am getting the below error

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin. [Failed SQL: (3098) INSERT INTO schema.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, `DESCRIPTION`, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('1', 'user', 'changesets/schemas/script1.sql', NOW(), 1, '8:b52bd973e60d550446b6f005206925c6', 'sql', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '4.17.1', '7953110735')]
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue ?